# parsing string using regex or php

Tags: php, regex, string, notepad++

To put simply, I'm trying to find and replace text with the wrapped xhtml tags without touching the surrounding text. Ideally I was going to use regex in Notepad++ but have had no experience with regular expressions and only limited experience with PHP,

For example:

```
Year: 2007    Registration: XYZS23
Transmission: Auto    Stock Number: AZ1234
Kilometres: 1280    Colour: Blue
Features: 
includes cruise control.
```

With the parsed text it would then look like the following:

```
<strong>Year:</strong> 2007    <strong>Registration:</strong> XYZS23
<strong>Transmission:</strong> Auto    <strong>Stock Number:</strong> AZ1234
<strong>Kilometres:</strong> 1280    <strong>Colour:</strong> Blue
<strong>Features:</strong>
includes cruise control.
```

so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for `[^\s{2,}]+:` and replace with `<strong>$0</strong>` or `<strong>\0</strong>` depending on the editor.

Here it is in TextMate!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aqfO.png

Comment: I'm using Notepad++ unicode under yucky Windows Vista if that helps? But when I use the above code it unfortunately replaces with the literal text (without quotes) "<strong>$0</strong>"

Comment: Did you try <strong>\0</strong> instead? I don't have Windows around to test on.

Comment: yes ... unfortunately it did the same and did a literal replace. i.e. "<strong>\0</strong>"

Comment: If that doesn't work it may just not match the whole field as $0. You can try ([^\s{2,}]+:) and replace with <strong>$1</strong> or <strong>\1</strong>.

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those variables work either. I find it odd that it executes the find regex properly but Notepad++ doesn't appear to acknowledge the regex in the "replace with" and simply replaces it with $1 or \1 instead of the variable.

Comment: Placing the regex in parentheses and using `\1` as a replacement worked for me in Notepad++.

Comment: wowzers! thanks aether! :) I can finally stop pulling my hair out! and thanks bill for trying to nut it out with me, i really appreciate it! :) thanks guys! :)

Comment: Putting the regex in parentheses was actually originally Bill's idea - I can't claim credit. Guess you just missed it. :)

Comment: oops! my bad >.< thanks again Bill :) now I just have to sort the problem out with Stock Number and package it into a macro and I'll be set! :P

Answer (score 0):

So - you will have to search for this:

```
<whitespace> <any non-null number of alphanumerical characters> : <whitespace>
```

Which will, when using **preg_replace** (regex in PHP) look like this:

```
$parsed = preg_replace("/([A-Z]+:)/", "<strong>$0</strong>", $original);
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, but is there a way to do this within Notepad++? I have tried using the regex expression without quotes, but it does a literal replace: ie. replaces each find with <strong>$0</strong>

Comment: That won't match the "Stock Number" field, though. You would need to do /[^\s{2,}]+:/ in NotePad++ and replace with <strong>$0</strong> I believe.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work Bill, sorry where do I need to use \0 Tim?

Comment: I'm sorry you need to do `[^\s{2,}]+:` in the search field and <strong>$0</strong> in the replace field. It's just a habit to do // when I'm dealing with regex. http://i.imgur.com/5aqfO.png

Comment: No worries bill, definitely close but unfortunately I must be doing something wrong, because its finding the correct text to replace but its then replacing each instance with <strong>$0</strong>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
search : ([a-zA-Z]+ *[a-zA-Z]*:)
replace: <strong>\1</strong>
```